# No HDMI sound on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, hdmi

I have my computer connected to my Sony TV, the HDMI video output works fine but I cant get the audio to work. I can see the HDMI output option in the sound settings but nothing happens. When I plug in my headphones the sound works fine

Do you guys have any solution to this ?

Comment: What happens if you connect your HDMI device and run in a terminal `pactl set-card-profile 0 hdmi-output-0`?

Comment: It says "no valid command specified" @Salem

Comment: Sorry that command is not right. Try this: `pactl set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo`. As your system may also have different names for the interfaces you can try to just write `pactl set-card-profile ` and hit TAB to see the suggestions.

Comment: @Salem I had the same problem and your suggestion worked. Maybe you can turn that into an answer?

Comment: @Kalli Have you solved your problem?

Comment: Maybe `pavucontrol` will help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run

```
pactl set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo
```

This should set the audio output to HDMI.

Answer (score -2):

Open a terminal using `CTRL`+`ALT`+`T` and type in the following command:

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

It works on 13.10 (for me, atleast.)